# Populate file contents in value field of a text box

Tags: php, javascript, html

I created a text box as follows-

```
<textarea name ="textbox" rows="20" cols="50" id ="textbox" style="background-color: #000000; font-size:14.5px; font-family:arial; color:#FFFFFF;"> </textarea>';
```

In the PHP script,I am trying to get the contents of a file and then trying to populate the value field of the textbox as follows :

```
echo '<script> document.getElementById("textbox").value = "'.$final1.'";</script>';

where $final1 = file_get_contents(FILENAME);
```

I see that there is nothing populated in the value field and neither do i see any output when I try to echo this variable. I tried giving a variable say `$test = "ABCD";` and populating this variable and it worked.

I know this has something to do with HTML special characters because my file has lot of special characters but I am not able to find a solution.

Kindly please help. Thanks!

Comment: did you try echoing $final1 by itself? you're probably not retrieving the file contents.

Comment: You are prone to hijacking most likely

Comment: I tried echoing the variable using htmlspecialcharacters and it worked.. But I am being able to populate that into the value field of the text box. Also I tried create another text box with populating the value field right there like as shown below -

Comment: <textarea name ="textbox" rows="20" cols="50" id ="textbox" style="background-color: #000000; font-size:14.5px; font-family:arial; color:#FFFFFF;">  '.$final1.'</textarea>';....and this worked...I dono why its not getting populated when I use javascript

Answer (score 0):

If you problem is related to the file you load having special characters in to that html/javascript does not like try this

```
$final1 = htmlspecialchars( file_get_contents(FILENAME) );
echo '<script> document.getElementById("textbox").value = "'.$final1.'";</script>';
```